# Setting and resetting value of variable in django template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I want to set and reset flag variable inside django template. Is there any way for doing that?

```
{% for software in softwares %}
    //here want to asign default value to flag( flag = False)

    {% for mysoftware in mysoftwares %}
        {% if mysoftware.name == software.name %}
        //here want to set value to True to flag( flag = True)
        {{ software.name }}<br />
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    //check flag here
    {% if flag == False %}
    Software not assigned.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to do this to my knowledge.  Perhaps precalculate a list of tuples in your view, and iterate over that instead - displaying the results.  e.g.:

```
{% for software, assigned in software_list %}
  {% if assigned %}
    {{ software.name }}
  {% else %}
    Software not assigned
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Then, in your view, just populate the software_list data with a simple python construct:

```
names = [mysoftware.name for mysoftware in mysoftwares]
software_list = [(software, software.name in names) for software in softwares]
```

And add this to your context.

It's often tempting to try to do too much in the template, and this isn't really what they're for.  You gain far better readability if you keep your logic in python, where it belongs.